# python mmap for jit code

Tags: python, python-3.3, jit, mmap

I am trying to emulate this tutorial (http://blog.reverberate.org/2012/12/hello-jit-world-joy-of-simple-jits.html) for writing a simple jit. I am not sure if the python interface for mmap supports the following use case. The C code (incase the link goes dead) looks like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  // Machine code for:
  //   mov eax, 0
  //   ret
  unsigned char code[] = {0xb8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc3};

  if (argc < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: jit1 <integer>\n");
    return 1;
  }

  // Overwrite immediate value "0" in the instruction
  // with the user's value.  This will make our code:
  //   mov eax, <user's value>
  //   ret
  int num = atoi(argv[1]);
  memcpy(&code[1], &num, 4);

  // Allocate writable/executable memory.
  // Note: real programs should not map memory both writable
  // and executable because it is a security risk.
  void *mem = mmap(NULL, sizeof(code), PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC,
                   MAP_ANON | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
  memcpy(mem, code, sizeof(code));

  // The function will return the user's value.
  int (*func)() = mem;
  return func();
}
```

My python code for the same looks like this.

```
code = [0xb8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc3]

import mmap
import ctypes

size_in_bytes = len(code) * 4
mem = mmap.mmap(-1, size_in_bytes, prot=mmap.PROT_WRITE | mmap.PROT_EXEC, flags= mmap.MAP_ANON | mmap.MAP_PRIVATE)
# mmap.mmap.move(mem, ctypes.addressof(code), size_in_bytes)

mem.write(ctypes.addressof(code), size_in_bytes)
ftype = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_void_p)

f = ftype(mem)
f()
```

However, running this gives me the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    mem.write(ctypes.addressof(code), size_in_bytes)
TypeError: invalid type
```

So my question is how do we get writable mmap pages and how to copy the data so it can be jitted. If this is not directly accessible from python, can I use the python c interface to use the underlying C implementation to do this ?

Most of the jit interfaces I looked at use llvm or some other underlying jit. But I couldn't quite figure out how PyPy does it. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your python list to a ctype array:

```
arr = (ctypes.c_int * len(code))(*code)
```

Then the addressof method works:

```
>>ctypes.addressof(arr)
47651024
```

Comment: Thanks rofls. I tried with this code after adding yours.  mmap.mmap.move(mem, ctypes.addressof(arr), size_in_bytes)
I get the error --> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    mmap.mmap.move(mem, ctypes.addressof(arr), size_in_bytes)
TypeError: move() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Comment: @ssarangi, I found that as well. This works: `mem.write(arr)` but I'm not sure if that's what you want at that point...

Comment: mem.write(arr) works and my next problem is the mem object assigned to the function pointer (ftype) being assigned as in the C code. The other thing is how does mem.write figure out how many bytes to write ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the following to "work", in the sense that the function is called.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import ctypes

code = bytes([0xb8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc3])
arr = ctypes.create_string_buffer(code)

ftype = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int)
f = ftype(ctypes.addressof(arr))
print("Ready to call f()!")
f()
```

Unfortunately, on my operating system (FreeBSD) this results in a segmentation fault, because data segments are not executable.

So I modified the code to incorporate `mmap`;

```
from __future__ import print_function
import ctypes
import mmap

code = bytes([0xb8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc3])
ftype = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int)

mem = mmap.mmap(-1, len(code), prot=mmap.PROT_WRITE | mmap.PROT_EXEC,
                flags=mmap.MAP_ANON | mmap.MAP_PRIVATE)
mem.write(code)
arr = ctypes.create_string_buffer(mem)

f = ftype(ctypes.addressof(arr))
print("Ready to call f()!")
f()
```

But this gives a TypeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jit.py", line 11, in <module>
    arr = ctypes.create_string_buffer(mem)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 68, in create_string_buffer
    raise TypeError(init)
TypeError: <mmap.mmap object at 0x8007cb928>
```

**Edit:** Looking at the code for `create_string_buffer` in `ctypes/__init__.py`, it only accepts `str`, `unicode`, `int` or `long`.

Simulating what `create_string_buffer` does might help, but I don't have time to try that right now.

**Edit2:** It seems that Python's `mmap` ([source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/mmapmodule.c)) ignores the PROT_EXEC flag. That would explain the segfaults.

Comment: I tried both the approaches and saw the same issues on OSX. I have looked at the approaches all the 3 jit's take. PyPy is the same one which I couldn't figure as to how they actually jit although I haven't dug into the code much. Numba essentially uses llvm jitter internally (llvmlite) project which I am trying to avoid. Pyston implements everything in c++ and I have seen the approach they take which is what I am familiar with in my use of llvm. I however wanted a barebones way of writing a jitter directly with python's mmap instead of having to make a c wrapper for it.

Comment: @ssarangi I found out why `create_string_buffer` failed, see edited answer. Maybe simulating it would help.

Comment: I tried doing this.. mem.seek(0)
arr = ctypes.create_string_buffer(mem.read(len(code))).. So after the mem.write(code) we seek to the beginning of the mem and then pass that to read len(code) bytes. However I still get the same Bus Error 10 on OSX. Similar to your previous example where you said the data segment wasn't executable. So is it illegal to use python's mmap to return executable memory?

Comment: @ssarangi Looking at the `mmap` documentation for 3.4.3, it doesn't mention PROT_EXEC at all. And in the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/mmapmodule.c) for mmap it's also not used. I have the sneaking feeling that it just ignores PROT_EXEC. That would certainly explain the errors.

Comment: That's my gut feeling too :). I managed to work around it for now using python c api and just sending the byte stream to the c api. That seems to work but it opens up a whole new can of worms :). For example type system (function signature). right now it's hard coded to a long f* (long). I am working around that too with using a list of list to pass the types down to the c api. :) (very hacky). I am wondering if there is a way to pass a ctypes function signature to the c api and decode it there.